# How to turn FileReader image preview example into Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, filereader

There's an example from MDN on how to use FileReader to show a preview image:

```
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /^image\//;

    if (!imageType.test(file.type)) {
      continue;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is the div output where the content will be displayed.

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how to use this in a Vue component. It seems to me the asynchronous part isn't that easy to handle, but I'm new to Vue, and maybe that's an advanced feature.

Answer (score 1):

Create a component with an `<img :src="src" id="img>` tag and `src` property in it's `data` object.  You could pass an idx prop from parent component along with a file if you would like to make a gallery and and it to an img id, because as we reference an image by id we need unique id for each `img` element.

Create a method `loadPicture`

```
loadPicture(file) {
   let self = this;
   let img = document.getElementById('img');
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
     self.src = e.target.result;
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}`
```

Then call  this method in `mounted` lifecycle

```
mounted() {
     this.loadPicture();
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8dnhh23o/
Multiple images example: https://jsfiddle.net/o1037uks/